# How can I use a loop to instantiate and specifically name a bunch of objects instead of writing similar instantiation lines a bunch of times?

Tags: c#, loops, instantiation

I achieved my desired results with my code (which I will show you first, and then explain). But now I want to achieve the same functionality using loops, and my problem is that my attempts so far have failed.

Successful code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextLooter
{
    public class Location
    {
        public int positionA;
        public int positionB;

        public Location(int aPositionA, int aPositionB)
        {
            positionA = aPositionA;
            positionB = aPositionB;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            Location city = new Location(1, 1);
            Location park = new Location(2, 2);
            Location town = new Location(3,3);
            Location woods = new Location(4, 4);
            Location meadow = new Location(5, 5);
            Location mountain = new Location(6, 6);
            Location temple = new Location(7, 7);
            Location circus = new Location(8, 8);
            Location gym = new Location(9, 9);
            
            Location location = new Location(0, 0);

            location = park;

            Console.WriteLine(location.positionA + ":" + location.positionB);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Above I created a Location class with a constructor, and in the Main method I instantiated 10 Location objects, set location equal to park, and wrote park's coordinates to the console. Everything is simple and intuitive. The functionality I am focusing on here is that while I am writing my code I can set location equal to whatever location I want by intuitively writing the name of the location.

The problem is, instead of 9 named locations to choose from, imagine if there were 900 cities of the world. I don't want to use 900 lines to instantiate 900 Location objects. I want to have those city names in some sort of collection and then use some loop to instantiate all of them, and most importantly while preserving the functionality of being able to intuitively write my code using the location names.

I understand that I am new and that the attempts I tried below may be far off the mark or flat out stupid, but here they are. I am reaching out to hopefully learn and discover some techniques in C# that could be useful for achieving this goal. Thank you for your help.

Instead of the 9 instantiation lines in the Main method:

Attempt 1:

```
string[] locations = { "city", "park", "town", "woods", "meadow", "mountain", "temple", "circus", "gym" };

int i = 1;
while (i < 10)
{
    Location locations[i] = new Location(i, i);
    i++;
}
```

Attempt 1 gets error CS0136 that says locations can't be declared as a local or parameter in this scope.

Attempt 2:

```
string[] locations = { "city", "park", "town", "woods", "meadow", "mountain", "temple", "circus", "gym" };

int i = 1;
while (i < 10)
{
    Location (locations[i]) = new Location(i, i);
    i++;
}
```

Attempt 2 gets error CS1955 that says Location can't be used as a function.

For these attempts I was hoping to achieve the goal of instantiating the 9 objects with their respective names.

What would you do to instantiate 900 Location objects while maintaining the ability to use the location names intuitively in the code?

Comment: Variable names cannot themselves be variable (also they would be in the wrong scope). Are you OK with different solutions that do not result in having variables with those names, but maybe a dictionary from name to value or something similar?

Comment: Yes as long as I can still code intuitively even if that means the city name comes after a . or something

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using LINQ and a dictionary:

```
string[] keys = { "city", "park", "town", "woods", "meadow", "mountain", "temple", "circus", "gym" };

Dictionary<string, Location> locations =
    keys
        .Select((x, i) => new { Key = x, Location = new Location(i, i) })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Location);

Location location = locations["park"];

Console.WriteLine(location.positionA + ":" + location.positionB);
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I achieved the same result by filling a Location array with a for loop, then filling the dictionary from the two arrays with another for loop. I read a bit about .Select, lambdas and Linq, but still cannot wrap my head around how this works. I'm thinking I'll have to use my aforementioned approach considering I want to iterate the Location objects' parameters so they are (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), etc., but I don't understand your approach enough to modify it. I learned a lot from this anyway, and I'm looking forward to studying this more when it is unavoidable.

Comment: Sorry for being an entitled meme. I was overloaded with a list of concepts I wanted to learn, but the project is finished now. I'll learn Linq well enough to modify this. Thanks again.